# How to make this code parallel ?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, performance, parallel-processing, parallels

I have written some codes in Vb.Net but it runs quite slow. How can I make it become parallel programming. I need to create 1000 objects of the same type. After initialization, each object will do the same task and the objects are not inter-related to each other.

```
Dim List as new List(of myObjectClass)

For i as integer = 1 to 1000
  Dim anObject as new myObjectClass()
  anObject.DoSomethingUseful()
  List.add(anObject)
Next
```

Any idea would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Parallel.ForEach. Create your 1000 items first and then run the expensive method in a parallel execution

```
Dim List as new List(of myObjectClass)

For i as integer = 1 to 1000
  Dim anObject as new myObjectClass()
  List.add(anObject)
Next

System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEach(List, Sub(item)
                                        item.DoSomethingUseful()
                                        End Sub)
```

Comment: is the Parallel.ForEach available for NET 3.5?

Comment: No, you didn't mention .net 3.5.

Comment: thanks James - the code was written in NET3.5 so I may need to find a way around.

Comment: Is there a good reason sticking to 3.5, lots a good stuff came with v4 and 4.5. If you can upgrade, I'll highly suggest you do.

Comment: that's the same question I've asked my boss so many times..I don't still get why the company still wants to stick with 3.5.  By the way, I've just tried the Parallel.ForEach you suggested, the parallel code took 905ms, while the normal for loop took 3250ms - big improvement!

Comment: Hi Jame, I am wondering after I have make the code run in parallel for each item : item.DoSomethingUseful(), can I further make the task within each item (i.e. the sub DoSomethingUseful() run in parallel as well ? )

Comment: You want to have a Parallel.ForEach within another Parallel.ForEach?

Comment: Not sure if that really makes sense, but technically it's possible according to this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12618500/2360972 But this is really getting a bit off topic from the initial question. If you have further question ask a new one and mark this as answered if you're happy with the answer so far.